# Classic ASP application hangs after sitting open in browser for long period of time

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP application that uses a SQL backend.  The app used Access until earlier this week, when I changed it to try to resolve this problem, to no avail.  The problem is that the users leave the site open in IE all day long, and may take an hour or more between uses.  After it's been sitting open for a while, when they try to make a request, the site hangs and eventually shows "page can not be displayed".  If they hit the back button, then refresh the page, it works fine.

I just changed the app pool from Integrated to Classic, so that might fix it, but if anyone has any other ideas, I welcome them.  There is one other site on IIS (7.5) and while a user is experiencing this hang, there is no large resource usage on the server.

Also, I've turned on Failed Request Tracking for anything that runs over 3 seconds.  I get log files when these hangs happen, but they say that the request returned status code 200, but it always seems to stop in the log at NOTIFY_MODULE_START - IsapiModule, Notification 128, Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER.  The Module Notification for that event shows NO_END in the duration.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

You could build a background AJAX / jquery pinger in Javascript that just pinged the server every 5 mins to refresh the session and you would never be logged out.

Comment: They are not being logged out, per se.  They don't have to log back in, but refreshing the page seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I assumed your login used the session ID but if your login / logout code does not depend on the session ID but a cookie for example then that is why your refresh works. My answer is still a valid fix and should be considered because the ajax ping would be the same as a page refresh but done silently in the background.

Answer (score 0):

On IIS sessions time out after a set period - the default  is 20 minutes.

What you could do is set a session variable on your landing page - eg

```
<% Session("Active") = "yes" %>
```

Then have a script on all your other pages to bounce you back to the landing page if the session does time out - eg

```
<% if Session("Active") <> "yes" then 
Response.redirect("mylandingpage.asp")
end if %>
```

Comment: I changed the session timeout to 480 (8 hours) and I'm still having the same issues.